# removes spaces while adding custom line in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

While adding new custom line between two points it takes a space/padding in the chart.

Here is my link:

[http://www.cygnusdevelopments.in/HTML/chart](http://cygnusdevelopments.in/HTML/chart)

To add new custom line, 1st select line radio type and then click anywhere...it will draw a line between two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by ordinal axis, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal).